# How to ignore some classes during train, test, val in yolo v8 without modifying dataset?

Tags: machine-learning, yolo, yolov8

I have a dataset which has 12 class which is indexed form 0 to 11. I want to ignore last 4 classes during train, test, val in yolov8. How to do that?

Comment: It seems like you have to modify labels and the dataset.yaml file in order to train or validate a model on a reduced number of classes. The names in the yaml file should represent all the categories that occur in the label files. If just delete the last 4 names in the dataset.yaml you will get the error during training when the first object of these 4 classes will appear. In the inference mode, you can use the 'classes=[]' argument to filter only relevant classes to predict.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [supervision](https://supervision.roboflow.com/quickstart/detections/) library to do exactly that.

Comment: `404 - Not Found` your link doesn't work.

Comment: @OriYardenPhD Looks like they changed website structure. You can still find it in "How to" -> "Filter Detections"